# Hot to deal with web requests in sequence by using ConcurrentQueue in WebApi?

Tags: c#, .net, api

The scenario is there might be 1,000 requests per second to call my api.Then I want each request could be handled in sequence.
My thought is every time the clients calling api, api would put a job into a static variable ConcurrentQueue.
Then another program will pull the ConcurrentQueue data, and deal with it.(like the diagram below) 
so, my question is 「question mark」 in the diagram. Is there any suggestion to implement it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DISTa.png)

Comment: Do the clients expect a response? Also make sure your question is, in text, in your question. Is your question _"How can I read a ConcurrentQueue"_?

Answer (score 0):

each call to the api is an independent thread and independent job
no need to for queue

1000 call to the web api will be 1000 threads executed at the same time

and if the method is async then no wait time to finish the call execution since no response back is required